# Correct usage of Appengine Sockets

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using the sockets api to communicate with the Apple Push Notification Service, although I'm not confident I'm using it correctly...

I have an initialization function where I establish my connection to APNS. However when is the correct time to call Close() on the connection? Or do I just leave it open and keep reusing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple specifically request that you don't close the connection with APNS and keep reusing it as long as possible.

> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications; don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack. You should leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an extended period of time—for example, if you only send notifications to your users once a day it is ok to use a new connection each day.

([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW2))

However, Apple will close the connection if you send them invalid data (such as notifications with invalid device tokens), so your code must be able to detect that and create a new connection when necessary. You should also read error responses from Apple, since those responses will let you know if you should re-send some of the notifications after you re-open the connection.

Comment: The answer is correct, I just want to add that you will have a hard time keeping a socket open for a long time on GAE: "Sockets may be reclaimed after 2 minutes of inactivity; any socket operation keeps the socket alive for a further 2 minutes." https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/

Answer (score 0):

That's a good answer from Eran but you may also check out `java-apns-gae`.

It's an open-source Java APNS library that was specifically designed to work (and be used) on Google App Engine.

https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/java-apns-gae